# Razor not compiling in using block

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, compiler-construction

We've added two extensions to HtmlHelper: `Content` and `Block`.  `Content` allows consumers to create `HtmlStrings` from razor code.  `Block` attempts to allow users to create html blocks with header and content sections.  I'm trying to understand why the the `razorContent` parameter doesn't compile inside of a using block.  I'd like to preserve the use of a using block because I think it looks very clean.  Is there a way to make this compile without changing the second argument on `Block` to `HtmlString`?

Razor:

```
@* uses of Html.Content compiles as expected *@
@Html.Content(@<span>foo</span>)
@{
    IHtmlString htmlString = Html.Content(@<span>bar</span>);
}
@htmlString


@* "@<span>header</span>" does not compile
 *
 * expected markup: 
 * <div class="header">
 *     <span>header</span>
 * </div>
 * <div class="content>
 *     <span>content</span>
 * </div>
 *@
@using (Html.Block(@<span>header</span>))
{
    <span>content</span>
}
```

Extensions:

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString Content(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, Func<object, HelperResult> razorContent)
    {
        var content = razorContent(null);
        return content;
    }

    public static IDisposable Block(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, Func<object, HelperResult> razorContent)
    {
        var content = razorContent(null);
        return new MyHtmlBlock(htmlHelper, content);
    }
}
```

MyHtmlBlock:

```
public class MyHtmlBlock : IDisposable
{
    private readonly TextWriter _writer;
    private readonly TagBuilder _contentTag;

    public MyHtmlBlock(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, IHtmlString header)
    {
        this._writer = htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer;

        var headerTag = new TagBuilder("div");
        headerTag.AddCssClass("header");
        headerTag.InnerHtml = header.ToHtmlString();

        this._contentTag = new TagBuilder("div");
        this._contentTag.AddCssClass("content");

        this._writer.Write(headerTag);
        this._writer.Write(this._contentTag.ToString(TagRenderMode.StartTag));
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        this._writer.Write(this._contentTag.ToString(TagRenderMode.EndTag));
    }
}
```

Comment: The methods expect a `Func<object, HelperResult>`, maybe you should call it using a lambda: `@Html.Content(o => new HelperResult(o))`... What is HelperResult?

Comment: `Html.Content` compiles correctly.  Only `Html.Block` in a using block doesn't.  HelperResult: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.helperresult(v=vs.111).aspx